Let $p$ be a prime and $p \le n$. Let $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$ such that $A^{p^m} = I$ show $A^p = I$.
As in the title, I'm looking to solve the following question:
Let $p$ be a prime and $p \le n$. Let $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$ such that $A^{p^m} = I$ for some positive integer $m$. Show $A^p = I$.
I'm a little confused about where to start, as I'm a bit rusty on linear algebra. I assume this has something to do with the minimal polynomial of $A-I$ since it is easily shown that $(A-I)^{p^m} = 0$.

This is false unless you meant $n \le p$. If that's what you meant, then yes, think about the minimal polynomial. It has to divide $(A - I)^{p^m}$ but it also has to have degree at most $n$.

The constraint should be $p\ge n$, otherwise the $3\times3$ Jordan block for the unit eigenvalue in $GF(2)$ will serve as a counterexample. If $p\ge n$, note that $(B-I)^p=B^p-I$ for any matrix $B$. Also, if $B$ is nilpotent, $B^n$ must be zero.

Thanks to both of you. This question is from a past qualifying exam, and I was confused about how to proceed under the assumption $n \ge p$ (since it seemed like it was supposed to be easy). I'm glad to know it ended up being a typo.
